# Invoke-AzVMReimage: The Reimage and OSUpgrade Virtual Machine actions require that the virtual machine has Automatic OS Upgrades enabled

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I'm creating VM using the following configuration which specifies -EnableAutoUpdate:

```
# Create virtual machine
Write-Host "Creating virtual machine '$vmName' in resource group '$resourceGroupName'";
$virtualMachineConfig = New-AzVmConfig -VMName "$vmName" -VMSize "Standard_D2_v3" -IdentityType UserAssigned -IdentityID "$($userAssignedIdentity.Id)" `
                      | Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -CustomData $encodedScript -Windows -ComputerName "$vmname" -Credential $Credential -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate `
                      | Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id `
                      | Set-AzVMSourceImage -PublisherName 'MicrosoftWindowsServer' -Offer 'WindowsServer' -Skus '2016-Datacenter' -Version latest `
                      | Set-AzVMBootDiagnostics -Enable -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $bootDiagStorageAccount.StorageAccountName;
```

But when I try to reimage VM get the following error:

```
Invoke-AzVMReimage: The Reimage and OSUpgrade Virtual Machine actions require that the virtual machine has Automatic OS Upgrades enabled.
```

What exactly need to be able to run reimage command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **vaguely** remember this feature been in preview for Azure VMs with ephemeral OS Disk. I didn't sign up for preview back then to can't repro.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ephemeral-os-disk-limited-public-preview/

hope this points you in right direction.